# Using the Vimeo API or other code, how can I tell when a video can be watched after uploading?

Tags: vimeo, vimeo-api, vimeo-player

After uploading a video using the Vimeo API, it is not instantly available for viewing, as some processing needs to be done by Vimeo to get it into their format. In the meantime if you load the soon-to-be-valid video link into a browser within an iframe, there is a message, "Sorry This video will be available for viewing shortly." instead of the video player, as the video is not yet available to view.

I've looked at the Vimeo API reference and did not find anything that seemed related. I also understand that I cannot access the contents of an iframe  using javascript code when the src resource is foreign to my domain.

Am I missing something? How can I do this?

Below is the iframe as it appears in my Angular app.:

```
 <iframe [src]="mySafeLink" width="640" height="480" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; fullscreen"
    allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Comment: If you look at the [API](https://developer.vimeo.com/api/reference/responses/video) you will see it has specific `upload.status` and `transcode.status` fields to allow you to check whether a video has finished uploading or transcoding.

Comment: @Herohtar, excellent! Thank you. Although the API link was of no value to me (perhaps later, since I know what fields are exposed), a search for * vimeo api transcode status * returned the answer as the first hit. Thanks again!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is this:

GET https://api.vimeo.com/videos/[video_id]?fields=uri,upload.status,transcode.status

The `upload.status` and `transcode.status` fields will return one of the following values:

`complete`
`error`
`in_progress`

To test it, create a request in Postman as follows: set the request type to GET and the URL as it appears above. Under Headers, add a Key named Authorization and set its Value to: bearer [your access token]

The brackets "[" and "]" should be dropped and replaced with the contents indicated.

Answer came from https://github.com/vimeo/vimeo.js/issues/89#issuecomment-437398447